# How to make a marker on a map semitransparent?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

I have a map from MapBox and I draw custom markers on the map which are circle images. When the user selects one I want the other markers to become semitransparent. I use `MarkerOptions` class to position my marker on the map but this class does not have a method to change marker's alpha. There is a deprecated class `MarkerViewOptions` which does have such method but it is deprecated and some functionality does not work with that class. How am I supposed to customize a marker on the map?
Here is my snippet of code

```
private void setMarker(QuestData questData, int adapterPosition) {
        final float latitude = questData.getLatitude();
        final float longitude = questData.getLongitude();
        final LatLng position = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        final boolean isMarkerSelected = selectedMarkerPosition < 0
                || adapterPosition == selectedMarkerPosition;
        final float alpha = isMarkerSelected ? 1.0F : 0.5F;
        final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().setPosition(position);
        // how to set marker alpha?
        final Marker marker = getMapboxMap().addMarker(markerOptions);
        final int markerDiameter = getResources()
                .getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.size_diam_circle_marker);
        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(questData.getPhotoUrl())
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                        .dontAnimate()
                        .circleCrop()
                        .override(markerDiameter)
                        .error(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
                )
                .into(new GlideIconMarker(marker, getContext(), markerDiameter));
        questDataMap.put(marker, questData);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you need to set a custom marker with any custom image you made that have the opacity you want. It's that solution ok for your cause or i'm missing something?

Comment: But how to change a bitmap's opacity given the fact that is rounded? Unfortunately Android SDK does not provide an API to change a bitmap's opacity.

Comment: alpha is not supported at the marker level but this can be done with a SymbolLayer. see https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-symbol-icon-opacity. Another approach would be to lower the alpha of the icon image used

Comment: You should need to set a image wich you had changed previously the opacity. It works for me in some cases.

Comment: @Tobrun, does MapBox have a tutorial on how to do that? I don't quite get how to correctly use `SymbolLayer`.

Comment: https://blog.mapbox.com/a-guide-to-the-android-symbollayer-api-5daac7b66f2c

Comment: @Tobrun thanks for the article. Yesterday, I managed to make a Bitmap transparent with the help of Canvas but when images on markers became semitransparent, the markers stopped reacting to my clicks. Why that might happen?